# How can I use format method in cpp?

Tags: c++

I met a problem when I attempt to use the **format** method.

My codes are like below:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <format> 

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("Hello World\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

When I use the command `g++ --std=c++20 format_test.cpp` to compile it, it reports an error: **no member named 'format' in namespace 'std'.**

By the way, the output of the command `g++ --version` is here:

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Why do you believe that std::format should exist?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support says gcc has not yet implemented "Text formatting" (search for P0645R10). In the meantime, you can use fmtlib.

Comment: I see you updated the question and it looks like you are using apple clang, which is usually a bit behind the upstream clang, so you should still be using fmtlib

Comment: `__has_cpp_attribute(__cpp_lib_format)` is probably false. q.v. [feature testing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test)